# Java - Regular expression with available format

Tags: java, regex

Could you please instruct me how I write pattern regex for the bellow format:

```
Set {0} = {1}
```

with: - {0}, {1} is any characters, start text is keyword "Set", to space, to {0}, to space, to "=", to space and then {1}.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell if you want to verify a string to be in the format of "Set {0} = {1}" or if you're wanting to know what is stored in {0} & {1}.

Either way you can use this pattern:

```
"Set (.+?) = (.+?)"
```

Pattern breakdown:

- `Set` - literal string followed by a space
- `(.+?)` - One or more characters captured into group 1, followed by a space
- `=` - literal string followed by a space
- `(.+?)` - One or more characters captured into group 2

It'll allow you to either verify the String format, or get what is at {0} & {1}.

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String setString = "Set aaa = bbb";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("Set (.+?) = (.+?)").matcher(setString);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Success");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Success
aaa
bbb
```

If setString = "SetX aaa = bbb", Then the result would be:

```
Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the question properly I guess this is what you are looking for you need regx for string
Set aa = bb.

```
boolean dPort; 
dPort = Pattern.matches("[S][e][t][\\s][A-Za-z]+[\\s][=][\\s][A-Za-z]+", "Set aa = bb"); 
System.out.println(dPort);
```